# Laravel - Map two relationships to one

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a model `events` where I store informations about events. Every event belongs to one `group`. `users` of a event-group have the ability to reply if they attend at the event or not. This information is saved in a separate table `event_replies`.

Now with a simple relationship I can get all the replies of the event:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventReply','event_id','id');
}
```

or I can get all users of the group

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User','group_id','group_id');
    }
```

But loading the replies does not load all the users that didn't reply.

What I want is: The relation should return ALL users of the group. If they replied, the value should return, if not: the value should be null.

Is it possible to combine/map the Users-Relationship with the Replies-Relationship?

### Edit

Here is an example how the JSON result should look like:

```
    [ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "group":1,
      "name":"Event 1",
      "replies":[ 
         { 
            "name":"user 1",
            "reply":1 // replied
         },
         { 
            "name":"user 2",
            "reply":0 // replied
         },
         { 
            "name":"user 3",
            "reply":null // NO reply in event_replies
         },
         { 
            "name":"user 4",
            "reply":1 // replied
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

### Edit 2

`Events`-Table:

```
id: int
name: String
group_id: int
```

`Users`-Table:

```
id: int
name: String
group_id: int
```

`event_replies`-Table:

```
event_id: int
user_id: int
```

Like I said before: My goal is to get a event with all users that belong to the group --> `user.group_id = event.group_id`. If they replied, the Reply should be in the user object. If not - the Reply object inside the user object should be null.

With a normal SQL query I would join all users and left join the replies.

Comment: I don't fully understand what data you are trying to retrieve. In Laravel, an "eloquent relationship" returns a Collection. The collection can be empty but it cannot be null. Do you want to fetch a collection of users who didn't reply?

Answer (score 2):

Get replies with user and define user relationship in EventReply model

```
public function replies()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventReply','event_id','id')->with('user');
}
```

EventReply.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

Comment: I need the other way around (see my edit). I want to get all users with their reply (if they replied) - If they not replied, "Reply" should be null

Comment: can you show you table structure with some row data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly, you want to "eager load" your `Event` model with nested `users` and their respective `replies`.

Get a single event:

```
$event = Event::find(1)->with('users.replies')->get();
```

Get all events:

```
$events = Event::all()->with('users.replies')->get();
```

Here's Laravel documentation about eager loading:

- https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Shouldn't the single event example be $event = Event::with('users.replies')->find(1);